# ROOM Single Database Multiple Entities, Insert Query for different Tables

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

I have a small query, I have been confused on how to insert an object into a different entity.
I tried a work around doing:

```
@Query("INSERT INTO card_table VALUES(:id, :pid, :question, :answer, :type, :completed)")
    suspend fun insertCard(id: UUID, pid: UUID, question: String, answer: String, type: CardType, completed: Boolean)
```

However, this has not worked.

My question is, how do I insert an object into different entity tables with a single database.

Note -> The insert() query works for inserting decks into the deck_table. The issue correlates to the card_table as I am unsure on how to reference it.

Thanks

database

```
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
    suspend fun insert(deck: Deck)

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertCard(card: FlashCard)

@Database(entities = [Deck::class, FlashCard::class], version = 8, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(DeckTypeConverters::class)
abstract class FlashCardDB : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun DeckDAO(): DeckDAO

    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: FlashCardDB? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context, scope: CoroutineScope): FlashCardDB {
            val tmpInstance = INSTANCE

            if (tmpInstance != null) return tmpInstance

            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    FlashCardDB::class.java,
                    "flash_cards_database"
                ).build() //.fallbackToDestructiveMigration() will causes users to loose data during migrations (use only for testing purposes)
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
```

tables

```
@Entity(tableName = "deck_table")
@Parcelize
data class Deck(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") var title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date") var date: Calendar,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "completed") var completed: Boolean
) : Parcelable {


@Entity(tableName = "card_table")
@Parcelize
data class FlashCard(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
    @ColumnInfo(name = "parent_id") var pid: UUID,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "question") var question: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "answer") var answer: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "type") var type: CardType,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "completed") var completed: Boolean)
    : Parcelable {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, how do I insert an object into different entity tables with a single database

- To insert object you need to put method with `@Insert` in interface or abstract class with `@Dao`
- When you build your project - Room will generate implementation of your `@Dao`-interface. It would be plain class, but written in Java (for `DeckDAO` interface generated class would be `DeckDAO_Impl.java`). Also Room will implement `@Insert`-method (since you tell in this method what object you want to insert and Room knows its corresponding table's name). Let's say (to be simple) that implementation of this method would be executing query `insert into _tableName_ values (...)`.

```
@Insert
suspend fun insert(deck: Deck) <-- Room will generate implementation "insert into deck_table values (..."

@Insert
suspend fun insert(card: FlashCard) <-- Room will generate implementation "insert into card_table values (..."
```

- To get access to this implemented class' methods you should put your dao-interface in abstract class that extends `Database`. After build Room will make for you implementation of this abstract class and you can invoke method `insert` in your example with just:

```
FlashCardDB.getDatabase().DeckDAO().insert(deck)
```

or

```
FlashCardDB.getDatabase().DeckDAO().insert(card)
```

- It's not necessary to create separate dao-interface for each entity. In theory you could use single dao-interface with all insert/delete/update/query-methods. Then all you need is to get access to all these methods through single `FlashCardDB.getDatabase().DeckDAO()` endpoint. You can put there 10 insert-methods with the same `insert` name but they should differ with parameter's type (it's just a method overloading) or you could use different method's names for clarity.
- Though in practice (and in most tutorials) insert-delete-update-query methods for different entities for convenience are placed in different dao-interfaces. To achieve that you should put all these dao-interfaces to Database class. Let's say:

```
abstract class FlashCardDB : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun deckDAO(): DeckDAO
    abstract fun cardDAO(): CardDAO
```

So decision is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm getting your question correctly you want to insert the card data into the database right? What you need to do is have a `DAO` for each database model. So your Card database model will have its own `DAO`:

```kotlin
@Dao
public abstract class CardDao {
    @Insert
    fun insert(card: Card)
}
```

```kotlin
@Database(entities = [Deck::class, FlashCard::class], version = 8, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(DeckTypeConverters::class)
abstract class FlashCardDB : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun deckDao(): DeckDao
    abstract fun cardDao(): CardDao
...
```

Kindly let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Oh I getcha, BUT, the DAO I used (from Google CodeLabs), uses an interface. So would I use two interfaces? and how would each interface know which table to insert into

Comment: Yh. you can use either an interface or an abstract class. For your second question, Room uses the `tableName` field in the @Entity annotation to determine which table to insert into.

Comment: But how does the interface understand which table it is referring to. As only the @Dao would be applied? or is it a chronological order  thing

Comment: No its not chronological. It uses the `tableName` field if specified or the class name if not specified to create the tables in the SQLite database. Oh okay. I think I get your question now. I didnt see this line in your original question earlier:
@Insert suspend fun insertCard(card: FlashCard). What error do you get when inserting a `FlashCard` entity into the db?

Comment: I replicated what I have working for a cardDao interface. However, it still doesnt work. What Im assuming is, the interface does not know which table I am reffering to.